# Running jasmine specs headlessly with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, phantomjs, poltergeist

I have been using jasmine-headless-webkit to run my jasmine specs on my Rails 3.2 app, but I recently switched over to phantomjs/poltergeist to run my request specs, so I am needing to upgrade my jasmine tests to also run on phantom. I'd like to get away from using xvfb on my CI server.

Does anyone have any good way to run jasmine tests using phantom in the console? I'm finding surprisingly little info about it on the web.

Comment: Did you using guard? If so then check gem [guard-jasmine](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine)

Comment: nope, I'm not using guard. I'm hoping there's a way to do it without guard.

Comment: Did you check some articles listed in https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Buzz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution which i found is setup guard-jasmine ([Guard::Jasmine outside of Guard](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine#guardjasmine-outside-of-guard)) and then add `guard-jasmine -u http://localhost:3001/` to your build script. Works pretty well on my jenkins. Also you need to install phantomJS on the server. In my case i needed also node.js

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I ended up doing.